# Substring and find from String not possible

Tags: c++, websocket, substr

i had found at all researches in the internet that you can make substr as well as find from a string (like i do it in java without any problems...). but this does not work in my case. i get the error: 'class String' has no member named 'find/substr'

web.cpp

```
#include <WebSocketsServer.h>
#include "web.h"
#include "lightControl.cpp"

lightControl lightcontrol;
WebSocketsServer *web::websockets;

void web::webSocketEvent(uint8_t num, WStype_t type, uint8_t * payload, size_t length){
    switch (type) {
        case WStype_DISCONNECTED:
        break;
        case WStype_CONNECTED: {
            IPAddress ip = websockets->remoteIP(num);
            // send message to client
            websockets->sendTXT(num, "Connected from server");
        }
        break;
        case WStype_TEXT:
        String message = String((char*)( payload));
        //SYNTAX "120-5-70-5" // R, G, B, W

        std::string delimiter = "-";

        //R Value
        std::string rValue = message.substr(0, message.find(delimiter));
        message = message.substring(message.find(delimiter) + 1, message.length);
        //G Value
        std::string gValue = message.substr(0, message.find(delimiter));
        message = message.substring(message.find(delimiter) + 1, message.length);
        //B Value
        std::string bValue = message.substr(0, message.find(delimiter));
        message = message.substring(message.find(delimiter) + 1, message.length);
        //W Value
        std::string wValue = message.substr(0, message.find(delimiter));
        message = message.substring(message.find(delimiter) + 1, message.length);

        lightcontrol.changeColor(rValue, gValue, bValue, wValue);
    }
};

web::web(){
    websockets = new WebSocketsServer(120);
    websockets->begin();
    websockets->onEvent(webSocketEvent);
}

void web::webSocketListener(){
    websockets->loop();
}
```

web.h

```
#include <WebSocketsServer.h>
class web{
    static WebSocketsServer *websockets;

    public: web();
    static void webSocketEvent(uint8_t num, WStype_t type, uint8_t * payload, size_t length);
    public: void webSocketListener();
};
```

Comment: `String` is not `std::string`

Comment: i know. but i found no solution for my problem:)

Comment: We don't know where `String` comes from.  We might be able to help if you could tell us.